# Why does this code get interpreted by python 2 instead of python 3?

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, python-3.x, terminal

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

x = input("Linda> ").split( )
print(x[0])
```

When I run this code in Mac Terminal, it is giving `SyntaxError: invalid syntax.`
Consider input as Linda> a b c. It should give 'a' as output.
But raw_input() works just fine which means code is working in Python 2.
What can be the issue?

Comment: how do you run your command?

Comment: Note that, last I checked, Python 3 is not installed by default on OSX: https://docs.python.org/3/using/mac.html#using-python-on-a-macintosh. Even if it is installed, it may not be installed in `/usr/bin/python3`.

Comment: python3 file.py  interprets the code as Python3 whereas python file.py interprets as Python2.